# Inserting javascript file into theme template?

Tags: templates, javascript, editor

Is there any way to insert an existing .js file into a themes editor in the appearances section? So that you can click on it and edit it like you can a PHP file or the CSS file, I haven't been able to find a way yet from searching.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the server you can create the file there (inside the theme folder) and edit it from the theme editor.